# ¿Cómo exportar csv con acentos y ñ en Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Estoy intentando exportar un *Pandas DataFrame* a un *csv*, el cual tiene acentos y ñ, con el siguiente código:

```
df.to_csv('Junio.csv', sep=';', encoding="utf-8")
```

Un detalle, es que en *jupyter* los acentos y las ñ están correctos. El problemas es al exportarlo.

Cuando abro el *csv*, las celdas me aparecen con algunos de los siguientes errores:

> Ã¡ , en vez de á
> Ã- , en vez de í
> Ã@ , en vez de é
> etc.

Comment: Estas usando Python 3.x?

Comment: es algo un poco raro, lo he probado en Google Colab y me ha funcionado

Comment: Los códigos que muestras justamente son code point de esos mismos caracteres utf-8, me da la impresión que el archivo es lo que esta bien, y el problema en todo caso lo tienes al abrirlo

Comment: Python genera el csv usando utf-8 (por defecto). En cambio Excel supone al leerlo que la codificación es cp-1252 y por eso se ve mal. Lo ideal sería poder decirle a Excel que lo lea como utf8 (pues es el estándar actual para alfabetos internacionales). Eso puede hacerse mediante la función de "Importar datos externos", pero no es que sea precisamente sencillo dar con ello. Así que una opción más simple puede ser decirle a pandas `encoding="cp-1252"` para que coincida con lo que excel espera por defecto. El inconveniente de esto es que fallará si el csv contiene otros alfabetos (ruso, chino..)

Answer (score 1):

En mi caso se genera correctamente el export a excel utilizando el encoding "latin1":

```
df_merge.to_csv('/tmp/merge.csv',index=False,encoding='latin1')
```

Saludos,

Comment: Siendo estrictos, el encoding que habría que usar sería "cp-1252" y no "latin1". De todas formas "latin1" funciona porque es un subconjunto de cp-1252. Mientras el csv no contenga niguna de las letras: `€ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹ŒŽ“”•–—˜™š›œžŸ` no habrá problema. Sin embargo observa que una de las letras "incompatibles" es el símbolo del euro (€)

Answer (score 0):

En cualquier versión de Python 3 (3.x), ya la codificación está estandarizada en utf-8. De manera que todas las cadenas son unicode por defecto.

Si estás trabajando con Python 2.x, es otra cosa porque la codificación por defecto es ascii, y de allí pueden venir ese tipo de inconvenientes.

Tu puedes cambiar la codificación por defecto a la que tu quieras, en ese caso sería utf-8, y eso lo haces con lo siguiente:

```
import sys
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

Quizás en Jupyter no te permite el setdefaultenconding. Por lo que te recomiendo, suponiendo que el dataframe se llame td entonces puedes hacer esto:

```
td.to_csv("td_frame.csv", encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: Estoy trabajando en Python 3. Por eso lo lee correctamente en jupyter. El problema es al exportarlo al csv.

Comment: Edité la respuesta

Comment: Si te fijas, es lo que intenté en la pregunta y no me funcionó.

Comment: tienes razón disculpa.

Comment: Muchas gracias igual @JeanGotopo

Answer (score 0):

También tuve el mismo problema y la mejor solución es utilizar en el encoding el ignore, hazlo sé que te va a funcionar

df.to_csv('Junio.csv', sep=';', encoding="ignore")